# Distance to coastline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, proximity

I have a shapefile of Ireland, and some xy coordinates plotted on top of it.

Is it possible to calculate distance to the coastline, for each XY?

I am an ArcGis beginner.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in details what do you want? You have a polygon shapefile of Ireland (one feature?). From what locations do you want to calculate the distance and to what locations (border of the polygon-s)?

Comment: Sorry, sure. I have plotted xy coordinates for houses in Ireland onto the map of Ireland (the ESRI shapefile you can obtain from the national statistics website). So I want to calculate the distance from each house/xycoordinate to the nearest coastline.

Comment: Use the generate near table tool.

Comment: What near feature do I specify?

Comment: I think the problem you have is your island/coastline is a polygon, not a line. In such a case the near distance is 0 since all points are within the polygon. You need to convert the polygon to a line, and then in features are points and near features are the line(s). If this isn't the issue, can you edit your question to explain what you mean by 'using the shapefile'? Perhaps a diagram or screenshot of your two datasets? Related/possible duplicates: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131902/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147479/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Euclidean Distance raster (distance from shoreline) then use add the Add Surface Information to populate each record in the shape file with the distance to the shoreline.